# Combining objects in nested loops with big data

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, performance, nested-loops

I'm trying to combine array objects to strings so that I get many combinations of results.(3000+) However, this following code does work, but it is insufficient/slow. It also tends to freeze.

I have tried with for loops as well but i get the same time taken.

Is there another way to make this more efficient? I have looked a bit at set interval, but made no progress there.

```
$.each(page_name, function(i, p) {
    $.each(extensions, function(ii, e) {
        $.each(query, function(iii, q) {
            var data = p + "." + e + "?" + q;
            dorks.push(data);
            $('#result').append(data + '\n');
            $("#amt").text(dorks.length);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: can you some part of `page_name` and `extensions` contents?

Comment: don't append in each iteration ... create the content and only insert it once when loop is done. Same with the length...insert it once when you have a final length

Comment: Also not clear where you call this from. Is it only done once or numerous times?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest the page_name, extensions and query are arrays ["a","b","c"] etc

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you, It makes sense now that you say it. I will do it your way! :) What do you mean, "not clear"?

Comment: meaning are you doing this process numerous times in a short period? Or just once in a while when data is requested?

Comment: @guest271314 ElementCollection.php?storeid=
ElementCollection.php?id=
ElementCollection.php?product=
ElementCollection.php?cartID=
ElementCollection.php?bookid=
example_element_group.php?storeid=
example_element_group.php?id=
example_element_group.php?product=
example_element_group.php?cartID=
....

Comment: @BlitZz The text of comment does not clarify what the input arrays are or the expected result. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . _"this following code does work, but it is insufficient/slow. It also tends to freeze."_ Can you reproduce the current result at stacksnippets, jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net, or plnkr http://plnkr.co? Presently, not clear, from perspective here, what you are asking?

Comment: @charlietfl Im calling this process once to generate the output combined from 3 different arrays. so example output: 1.1?=1 - 1.1?=2 - 1.1?=3 - 2.1?=1, 2.1?=2